# why do some functions within a python class require the use of brackets and others dont

Tags: python, class, pandas

Below I have defined a basic class with some functions.

I am not sure of the best way to pass data from one function to be used in another.

My solution was to pass a dataframe as a parameter to the function. I am sure there is a better and more technically correct way so please call it out.

What I am trying to understand is why some functions in the class require the () to be used when calling them and others you can call just using the function name.

Once a ASX object called "market" is initiated The two examples are:

1. market.all_companies()

> Returns: a dataframe

2. market.valid_industry

> returns a series

```
class YourError( Exception ): pass

class asx(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        try:
            #initialise
            self.name = name

            #all companies on asx downloaded from asx website csv
            df = pd.read_csv('http://asx.com.au/asx/research/ASXListedCompanies.csv', skiprows=1)
            df.columns = ["company","asx_code","industry"]
            df["yahoo_code"] = df["asx_code"]+".AX"

            self.companies = df
            self.industry = self.all_industry(df)
            self.valid_stocks = self.valid_stocks(df)
            self.valid_industry = self.valid_industry(df)

        except: 
            raise YourError("asx companies CSV not available")

    def all_companies(self):
        return self.companies

    def valid_industry(self,df):
        return df["industry"].value_counts()

    def all_industry(self,df):
        return df["industry"].value_counts()

    def valid_stocks(self,df):
        return df[(df["industry"]!= "Not Applic") & (df["industry"]!="Class Pend")]

market = asx("asx")
market.all_companies()
market.valid_industry
```

Comment: `market.all_companies` returns a **function**. Given you call it, the code you defined in the `def all_companies` will be executed and you get the result.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem isn't market.valid_industry also a *function*? and therefore when it is executed shouldn't I get the result? still not sure why the brackets are only needed in the first instance?

Comment: not since you wrote `self.valid_industry = self.valid_industry(df)` it is the **result** of a function. That *can* be a function, but here it is a dataframe.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how do I write them both so they are both functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions require `()` but you're doing some nasty stuff in you `__init__` where you replace function with a series.

```
self.valid_industry = self.valid_industry(df)
```

this will overwrite the function `valid_industry` to no longer be a function on the instance created but to be value returned from `self.valid_industry(df)`

don't use same name for member properties and methods and all will make sense.

For your methods you don't need to pass in `df` as argument as you have it assigned to `self.companies` so your

```
def valid_industry(self,df):
    return df["industry"].value_counts()
```

becomes:

```
def valid_industry(self):
    return self.companies["industry"].value_counts()
```

Comment: Thanks user3012759 and Willem Van Onsem thanks I see I have overwritten the function. How can I best write the valid_industry function which requires the basic dataframe (df) to manipulate. I tried not to pass it to the function and instead use df as a variable defined in the initialisation but this didn't work.

Comment: you assign it in `__init__` to `self.companies` so use `self.companies` in your methods instead of `df` passed in. also edited in the answer

Comment: @yoshiserry I would recommend you do some reading about python classes/methods/instance attributes

Comment: Thanks all for the great comments will do

Comment: what if I didn't want to assign self.companies = df, how could I refer to this in the valid_companies method? when I do so without initialising self.companies and just try and return df I get the error "df is not defined"

Comment: you have to assign it to `self.something` otherwise it won't be available

Comment: but self.something needs to be different to the name of the function in the class. So the something could be get_all_stocks and then the function name to make it short and easy to call could just be object.stocks()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141555/discussion-between-user3012759-and-yoshiserry).